# How can I programmatically create an iscsi target on linux?

Tags: java, linux, iscsi

I am using linux's default iscsi server. It is configured to be a target.
Now, I'd like to programmatically add a target, that is I give a disk image path ex. /home/me/disks/image.img and I set it as a target, with an iqn and such. This has to be done at runtime, that is if I add a new target other targets still have to be available.

Would this be possibile? I'd like to accomplish this in java but it isn't a strict requirement...

Answer (score 0):

if you want a java implementation of iscsi you can use http://jscsi.org/